# Set and Declare statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I use the below, the query is running indefinitely -

```
declare @start_date date
declare @end_date date

set @start_date='2021-08-17'
set @end_date=dateadd(d,1,@start_date)
```

WHERE

```
and ((e.REG_DT_TM  >= @start_date   and   e.REG_DT_TM  < @end_date )
or (e.PRE_REG_DT_TM  >= @start_date   and    e.PRE_REG_DT_TM  < @end_date ))
```

when I use date condition as below in where statement instead of declare and set it executes in 47 seconds -

```
and ((e.REG_DT_TM >= cast (dateadd(Day,-1,getdate()) as date)   and    e.REG_DT_TM < cast (getdate() as date )) 
or (e.PRE_REG_DT_TM >= cast (dateadd(Day,-1,getdate()) as date)   and    e.PRE_REG_DT_TM < cast (getdate() as date )))
```

please can you help me identify why is this happening, as I need to use declare and set statement. Or how can I change my 'WHERE' condition to include @start_date & @end_date

Comment: In the second `WHERE` clause you have commented one condition out. It's probably `OR` that makes your query slow, because the DBMS is no longer using an index range scan, but runs through the whole table sequentially.

Comment: Sorry, I copied that way but in actual it is not commented out.

Comment: and ((e.REG_DT_TM >= cast (dateadd(Day,-1,getdate()) as date)   and    e.REG_DT_TM < cast (getdate() as date )) 
or (e.PRE_REG_DT_TM >= cast (dateadd(Day,-1,getdate()) as date)   and    e.PRE_REG_DT_TM < cast (getdate() as date )))

Comment: Okay, I've edited your request accordingly to avoid confusion. (Because `OR` or not `OR` would have been the obvious explanation.)

Comment: SQL Server is generating a different execution plan when using parameters. You need to "Paste Your Plan" both ways around in order for someone to assist.

Comment: No point in debugging performance issues based on a fragment of a query.

Answer (score 0):

I just added a command at the end and it executed my query with declare and set statement in seconds. It was related to the different execution plan I guess. However now running fine.

```
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```